# Find a particular string in an string array

Tags: c#

I am trying like this:

```
int Quantity = Array.FindIndex(lineValues, x => x.Equals("Order 1 QTY"));
```

It is passing for the same string. But I want it to get passed even if there are no spaces between the string.

I want it to get passed with both the string:

> "Order 1 QTY"
>   "Order1QTY"

I want to check for just string excluding spaces.

Comment: Maybe with the help of [Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701992/regex-space-or-no-space)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# string comparison ignoring spaces, carriage return or line breaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718965/c-sharp-string-comparison-ignoring-spaces-carriage-return-or-line-breaks)

Comment: Then You will have to buffer the String in another tmp variable, delete the blanks of it and then search again with a search pattern also without blanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use a regular expression:

```
var regex = string.Format("Order\s*{0}\s*QTY", 1);
int Quantity = Array.FindIndex(lineValues, x => Regex.Matches(x, regex));
```

The regular expression I'd use would be something like this:

```
Order\s*1\s*QTY
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1jCVIqj7pbBg7wpP)

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
string y = "Order 1 QTY";
int Quantity = Array.FindIndex(lineValues, x => x.Equals(y) || x.Equals(y.Replace(" ","")));
```

Comment: Probably he also meant to have all permutations of "zero or one blanks"?

Comment: I just want the string character excluding white spaces in between .

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: `var lineValues = new string[] { "  Order 1 QTY  ", " Order 1QTY" };` returns `-1` here, while I expected `2`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, yes if the strings were that disparate you'd get some weird results.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, remove all the whitespace from your test string, then compare that to "Order1Qty".

```
int Quantity = Array.FindIndex(lineValues, 
    x => x.Replace(" ", "").Equals("Order1QTY"));
```