# RegEx find string containing numbers with one space, two spaces or no space at all followed by / and four numbers

Tags: regex, vba, string, ms-word

I need to use RegEx to find a string in Word document. The string contains numbers{1;5} **with one space, two spaces or no space at all** followed by **/** and four numbers{4} which denotes a year in which the document was created.

The strings I need to find are like these:

- `45 /2017`
- `125 /2019`
- `1245 /2018`
- `12577 /2019`
- `37589 /2017`

but sometimes there is no space in between:

- `45/2017`
- `125/2019`
- `1245/2018`
- `12577/2019`
- `37589/2017`

and sometimes there is two spaces:

- `45  /2017`
- `125  /2019`
- `1245  /2018`
- `12577  /2019`
- `37589  /2017`

but it's always in the same place - the space or two spaces. It's always after the first string of numbers, which are never more than 5 digits - therefore I type [0-9]{1;5} in RegEx.

But when I tried to build this RegEx expression in Word's Ctrl+H find and replace dialog box, and I test it against the Word's document I cannot build universal expression to find these strings with space and no space. The ? is not working for me. I've read [here](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm) that ? should find one space or no space, but when I'm testing it in my Word document it finds a string with two spaces inside, but not the one with one space or no space at all.

Here are the RegExs I've tried, which failed to match both strings with no space inside like `4125/2019`, as well as similar strings with one or two spaces:

1. `[0-9]{1;5} ?/[0-9]{4}`
2. `[0-9]{1;5}\s?/[0-9]{4}`
3. `[0-9]{1;5}[ ]{0;2}/[0-9]{4}`    this gives an error but `[0-9]{1;5}[ ]{1;2}/[0-9]{4}` finds `125 /2019` but doesn't find `125/2019` and `12577/2019`.

In Polish version of MS Word/Excel we use `;` instead of `,` in formulas, but I tried it all with colon or semi-colon interchangeably.

I've read these sources: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops/22542835#22542835)

and

[Regex- Space or no space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701992/regex-space-or-no-space)

[Analyst_Cave](https://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/)

[Regular Expression Tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html)

Comment: Never try to use RegEx to manipulate Word data inside a document - it can't work. You need to use Word's built-in Find functionality with wildcards (Word's version of RegEx).

Comment: So Word's find and replace wildcards and VBA RegEx is something different? Is the syntax different?

Comment: Syntax is different (not as powerful) but the reason is that the result remains *in the context of the Word document*. RegEx can only work on a string, which will have no reference to the context of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Word *wildcard* Find expression like:

```
<[0-9 ]{1;7}/[0-9]{4}>
```

without the need to involve the RegEx library.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
([0-9]{1,5})([ ]{0,4})([/])([0-9]{4})
```

or

```
([0-9]{1,5})([\s]{0,4})(/[0-9]{4})
```

According to the test, all three are good.

[image]

Comment: If the space is between both numbers strings coded as ```([ ]{0,4})``` or ```([\s]{0,4})``` than why the first digits sequence you wrote ```([0-9]{1,7})``` in both cases, which suggests there can be up to seven digits, even though I said its never more than 5 digits? The first number is always below 99999.

Comment: @michal roseler, I missed. Crrect that to {1,5}.

Comment: Thank you for that answer @Dy.Lee. It solves my problem and it finds the desired strings flawlessly. I just picked this other answer by macropod because he showed me, that I don't need Regex at all to achieve the goal of the macro I'm writing now. His solution will make my whole code simpler. But your answer works fine and I'll use it in the future for sure. Thx.